# Question on non-diagonal Einstein Field Equations and the interpretation of Energy-momentum tensor components

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Considering an EFE like:

$$\begin{pmatrix}G_{00}& 0 & 0& G_{03}\\0 &G_{11} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & G_{22}&0\\ G_{30}& 0& 0&G_{33} \end{pmatrix} = 8\pi\begin{pmatrix}T_{00}& 0 & 0& T_{03}\\0 &T_{11} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & T_{22}&0\\ T_{30}& 0& 0&T_{33}\end{pmatrix}.  \tag{1}$$

then, write it in a tetrad frame:

$$\begin{pmatrix}G_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}& 0 & 0& G_{\hat{0}\hat{3}}\\0 &G_{\hat{1}\hat{1}} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & G_{\hat{2}\hat{2}}&0\\ G_{\hat{3}\hat{0}}& 0& 0&G_{\hat{3}\hat{3}} \end{pmatrix} = 8\pi\begin{pmatrix}T_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}& 0 & 0& T_{\hat{0}\hat{3}}\\0 &T_{\hat{1}\hat{1}} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & T_{\hat{2}\hat{2}}&0\\ T_{\hat{3}\hat{0}}& 0& 0&T_{\hat{3}\hat{3}} \end{pmatrix}.  \tag{2}$$

I saw all sorts of papers doing extensively calculations using tetrads in non-diagonal EFE, and all that seems to converge to two main points: 1) To simplify the expressions and 2) to give physical meaning. But I'm not certain if even in the case of $(2)$, the $T_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}$ would be the energy density!

> When, we are allowed to call $T_{00}$ the energy density; just when we rewrite the whole expression in a tetrad or not?

Comment: do you know what the non-diagonal terms in tensor form mean? (i do, but you should too)

Comment: Well, if you could, elaborate more. But I was quite clear, showin that I don't know for sure the whole saga with the usage of tetrads. Again, try to write a answer if you could.

Comment: Also, if tetrads wasn't that important people would not use it. Now, what I'm asking is: Can I say that $T_{00}$ is the energy density, or $T_{30} = T_{03}$ ARE THE ENERGY FLUX, just when I use tetrads (a ortonormal frame) or not? I don't see why you are asking if I know or do not know things, since every time I read that the interpretation of these components occurs when the one uses tetrad frames.

Comment: I was just asking to check. Anyway, they have the same interpretation, but the numerical magnitude of those terms in the tetrad form will be pretty meaningless. Physics is very messy like that: the covariant components are conserved but cannot be plotted as pointing in any direction, the contravariant components can be plotted to give directions, but cannot be conserved. The tetrad form gives up both, but can be easily connected with spinors.

Comment: i.e. you can just always work in tetrad form, but when you need the conservation, you must remember to convert to covariant, and if you need to find the directions, you have to remember to convert to contravariant.

Comment: Ok, I agree. But you didn't answer my question, I'm afraid.

Comment: For instance. I have a metric tensor that returns me a Einstein tensor like $(1)$, ok? Then I want to use the energy-momentum tensor of electromagnetism. When I write the Energy-momentum tensor with this metric I realize that the tensor is just like $(1)$. So I match the EFE. In this case, therefore, can I call the first EFE as a equation for the energy density?Like, $T_{00} = \rho_{em}$? Or to say that, I need to write everything in a tetrad basis?

Comment: It should be (1). If it is in tetrad basis, you can make do with the calculations, but when you want to work out what the conserved quantities are, you need (1)